# ¿Cómo puedo insertar un query en la base de datos usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

Tengo un query, el cual me esta generando una lista de datos. Quisiera crear una nueva tabla con una columna que tenga los datos del query ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Este es el query

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu caso, yo crearía una Migration con la consulta de creación de la tabla (desconozco si desde Eloquent se puede crear una tabla dentro de un model, pero creo que no).

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('incidencias_resultado', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('resultado');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('incidencias_resultado');        
}
```

*Recuerda ejecutar el php artisan dentro del proyecto para que los cambios de la migration se propaguen.*

Entonces, una vez con la tabla "incidencias_resultado" creada, haría un insert into desde el modelo, ya que los datos se guardarían dentro de la variable $data

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();

DB::table('incidencias_resultado')->insert($data);

DB::commit();
```

La idea sería esta

EDIT:

Si quieres, puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de usar un fichero Migration.

```
DB::beginTransaction();

//Comprobamos que exista la tabla. En caso que no, la creamos.
if (!Schema::hasTable('incidencias_resultado')) {
{
     DB::statement('CREATE TABLE incidencias_resultado (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, resultado text, PRIMARY KEY (id));')
}

$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();

DB::table('incidencias_resultado')->insert(['resultado' => $data]);

DB::commit();
```

EDIT2:

Para que no se registre un único registro y se guarde registro a registro, yo haría lo siguiente:

- Crear una tabla donde se guarde el campo "rif" y el "resultado"
- Hacer un json_decode de $data
- Recorrer esa variable y ir guardando los resultados

```
DB::beginTransaction();

//Comprobamos que exista la tabla. En caso que no, la creamos.
if (!Schema::hasTable('incidencias_resultado')) {
{
     DB::statement('CREATE TABLE incidencias_resultado (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, rif text, resultado text, PRIMARY KEY (id));')
}

$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();

$data_decoded = json_decode($data)

foreach($data_decoded as $record){
    DB::table('incidencias_resultado')->insert(['rif' => $record[0], 'resultado' => $record[1]]);
}

DB::commit();
```

Seguro que hay algún que otro error (sobretodo a nivel del json_decode y foreach) pero es normal dado que no lo puedo probar en tu entorno. Pero la idea sería esta.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\laragon\www\bduproject\app\Http\Controllers\ATC\AtcController.php on line 28

Comment: me genera este error en el ->insert($data);

Comment: Disculpa, el campo del insert debe ir en una array. A ver ahora...

Comment: me genera este error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `incidencias_resultado` (`resultado`) values ([{"rif":"G200099976"},{"rif":"J070133805"},{"rif":"J300619460"},{"rif":"J001036865"},{"rif":"J000029610"},{"rif":"G200008261"},

Comment: Borra la tabla mediante un Drop table y vuelve a pasar el código, creo que el fallo estaba en que no tenía ningún campo Id. Ahora sí y se irá rellenando de forma autoincremental. A ver si así funciona...

Comment: en donde debo cerrar la llave del if?

Comment: lo he podido resolver amigo... pero se me crea una nueva fila con los datos, y en un solo campo se insertan todos los valores, yo quisiera una columna donde se me inserten uno por uno los valores creando una especie de lista, gracias por ayudarme de igual manera... alguna sugerencia para lo de la columna?

Comment: Hola. Disculpa la demora... Entiendo, pues deberías hacer el insert por cada resultado de la variable $data. Al fin y al cabo, $data tiene pinta de ser un json, con lo que, haz un json_decode de $data y, el resultante, haz un foreach. Entonces, por cada registro del foreach, haces un insert.

Pasos a seguir:
     1.- Borrar la nueva tabla y modificar el script de creación para que tenga la columna Id (autoincremental), una columna llamada "rif" y otra llamada "resultado"
     2.- Hacer un json_decode de ($data)
     3.- Hacer un foreach para hacer insert de cada resultado

Comment: He editado de nuevo con la propuesta. A ver que tal...

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo!! me ha funcionado de esta manera

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro mucho. Gracias por el feedback Oscar ;)